# Он вспомнил тот день и как его провел. Правильно ли?

Tags: однородные-члены, члены-предложения

У Лопатина:

Запятая между главной частью и придаточной, присоединяемой простым союзом или союзным словом, не ставится:

г) если придаточная часть, благодаря союзам и, или, включается в ряд однородных членов: Во время работы и когда вышел фильм, я не очень-то разобрался в нем (газ.); И вспомнил незабвенный «Фрегат «Палладу» и как Григорович вкатился в Париж лет восемьдесят назад! (Булг.); Ему вдруг захотелось тепла и чтоб зима тоже была теплая (Ард.); Приезжай через неделю или когда тебе захочется.

У Розенталя:

Не следует соединять в качестве однородных синтаксических элементов члены предложения и придаточные предложения. 
Следует, впрочем, заметить, что не только в устной речи, но и в речи письменной нередко встречаются случаи соединения при помощи сочинительных союзов разнородных синтаксических конструкций – члена предложения и придаточного предложения, например: Государь тотчас вспомнил вашу фамилию и что вы были в Вятке (Герцен);

Выходит, что по Лопатину соединять в качестве однородных синтаксических элементов члены предложения и придаточные предложения можно, а следуя Розенталю, - нельзя?

Answer (score 2):

Не "нельзя", а "не следует". Разные вещи! Скажем так: хороший русский язык этого не рекомендует.
И правда, подобные фразы выглядят не вполне корректно.

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание: справочник представляет собой не пособие по стилистике. Цель данного справочника объяснить постановку знаков препинания в тех или иных синтаксических конструкциях. А поскольку такие конструкции встречаются и в художественной литературе (пусть они и неправильны!)авторы включили эти конструкции в справочник, чтобы показать, что запятая в таких случаях не ставится. Так что никакого противоречия.

Comment: У Розенталя (в отличие от Лопатина) это именно в справочниках по _стилистике и литературной правке_.
Примечательно, что он отделяет грамматически недопустимые примеры (в первом абзаце процитированного в вопросе пункта) от стилистически неудачных (во втором абзаце).
http://rosental-book.ru/styli_xlvi.html
https://www.gumer.info/bibliotek_Buks/Linguist/rozent1/05.php

Comment: –@Alex_ander, вот именно  – в справочнике по стилистике.